# Google chrome asks to save password in Internet Explorer

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, passwords

I've been noticing that when I'm logging into a website, Internet Explorer displays a message at the top of the window: "Do you want Google Chrome to remember this password?" I have seen it come up on computers with Chrome installed and WITHOUT Chrome installed.

**Why is this happening and how can I get this not to appear anymore in IE?**

Comment: You've seen it on PCs *without* Chrome installed? That makes no sense... Try going to `Tools (or Gear icon or Alt+X) / Manage Add-ons` and disable anything Google-related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say Chrome is not installed, what exactly do you mean? Chrome is not just a browser. There is an IE addon called Chrome Frame which doesn’t require using (or even having installed) the Chrome browser. You need to disable the [Chrome Frame](http://www.google.com/chromeframe) addon from the IE addin-manager (*Tools⇨Manage add-ons*):

[image]

Comment: Does the ChromeFrame utilize password storage for Chrome?

Comment: Most of the time people forget about the add-ons. :D

Comment: @C-dizzle, Chrome Frame basically just embeds a mini Chrome browser in IE, just like how IE Frame embeds a mini IE browser in Chrome or Firefox. As such, when you use IE while Chrome Frame is installed and enabled, it acts just like the Chrome browser and uses exactly the same storage mechanisms for cookies, logins, passwords, etc. only in a slightly different location (e.g., the `UserData` folder is located within a subdirectory of the normal IE storage directory instead).